# Bit Padding (C)

Tags: c, padding, bit, sign, short

I have this code: (assuming short ints are 16 bits wide, and ints are 32 bits wide)

```
short int x = -5;
int y;
y = x;
```

Does padding on the left with the sign bit to increase precision change the value of a negative number?

Comment: There is most likely no padding.

Comment: Can you please explain why there is no padding

Comment: `x` is sign-extended during the assignment to `y`. The value, interpreted as a signed integer, does not change.

Comment: No, the value of a `short` can be assigned to an `int` without any change to the value. But not the other way round when the number of bits in `short` is fewer than those of `int`.

Comment: There is not need for padding.  Any padding in `short` or `int` would only reduce the range that the type may represent.  Padding would be unusual with current CPUs.

Comment: Likely the OP uses the term padding for sign-extension.

Comment: Unless your platform uses integers with padding bits, there is simply no padding. And even iff there are padding bits, their usage is transparent to the application code, unless you use "dirty tricks".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does padding (sign-extension) on the left with the sign bit to increase precision change the value of a negative number?

Taking into acount [@Amin Negm-Awad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42910368/bit-padding-c#comment72920291_42910368), when a variable is assigned from one type to another, **and** the *value* is representable in both types, like -5 as in `int` or `short`, there is no *value* nor precision change.

This applies if a type is `int`, `short`, `char`, `float`, etc.   It also applies if integer types are 2's complement or not.  The size of the type makes no difference.  Endian makes no difference,  The *value* is preserved.